# An alias that just prints the named directory?

Tags: alias, bash

I'm kind of just realizing how powerful the terminal can be. My question is essentially if I can create an alias that just prints the name of a directory. For example, I could easily make an alias such as "alias sitename="cd ~/sites/path/to/my/site/". But what I want is an alias that only prints the directory name so that I can use it for several things. So that, for example, if I wanted I could just say cd "alias", or mv from-dir "alias".

Is there a way to do this? I've tried and it seems to recognize the alias if I just type it in: it will report "alias" is a directory. But if I try to couple it with another command, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `alias`, what you are after is an environment variable

```
$ export SITENAME="~/sites/path/to/my/site/"
$ cd $SITENAME
```

Bash is quite picky over syntax - note the lack of spaces in the export and the `$` when you use it.

Comment: It does not need to be exported to the environment: a regular shell variable will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable, simply

```
d=/path/to/some/directory
echo $d
cd $d
mv somedir $d/
```

You don't need to use an *alias* here, a *variable* is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set a variable, not an alias. Such as, 
`sitename=/home/jimbo/`.  Then, `cd $sitename` would put you at `/home/jimbo/`.

If you want this variable to have permanence (i.e. you don't have to set it every time you open a new session), then you can make it an environmental variable using the `export` command or add it to your `.bashrc` file (typically located at `$HOME/.bashrc`) using the line:  `sitename=/home/jimbo/`.

FYI, `$HOME` is another environmental variable that's equivalent to `~/`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a variable is the simplest solution. You could get fancy and use an array:

```
mydir() { echo "/my/directory"; }
```

To display the value

```
mydir
```

To use the value, you need some extra puncuation

```
cd $(mydir)
cd `mydir`
```